# Inexplicable 500 error ASP.NET HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

Here's my code:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1111");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world");
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Debug.Write("done!");
```

And here's the error

An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I pretty much followed this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx with a few edits to try to fix, but to no avail.  I don't think it's a problem with the remote server - it's a test one I set up in SOAPUI.

Comment: Well, see, the problem is that the remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. What happens when you make a similar request with PostMan or similar testing tool?

Comment: seems the issue is in your server side as the 500 Internal Server Error comes from there. I would double check server setup, maybe it does not accept the format of the request you're sending

Comment: Well, your request body is most definitely not `"text/xml"`, even though you say it is.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I changed the url from a test one to a live one, but got a new error: An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine.  Any idea what that would be, or better, how to ignore it?  Also changed my code to real xml